# DYGRAPHS: Show warning when disable small graph in range selector

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I disabled the small graph in range selector using: 
`showInRangeSelector: false,` 
but I'm getting warning sign like this: [image]
I can't seem to find where is the bug.

Updated with code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://dygraphs.com/2.0.0/dygraph.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://dygraphs.com/2.0.0/dygraph.js"></script> 
<div id="hello" class="chart"></div>
</head>
<body>
<script type = "text/javascript">

var hello = [
            [new Date("2016-03-06"),[10,20,30],[11,11,11]],
            [new Date("2016-03-07"),[10,20,30],[15,15,15]],
            [new Date("2016-03-08"),[10,20,30],[32,32,32]],
            [new Date("2016-03-09"),[10,20,30],[18,18,18]],
            [new Date("2016-03-10"),[10,20,30],[26,26,26]],
            [new Date("2016-03-11"),[10,20,30],[31,31,31]],
            [new Date("2016-03-12"),[10,20,30],[9,9,9]],
        ],

a = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("hello"),hello, 
    {
        labels: [ "Date", "Mean" , "Scatter"],
        customBars: true,
        showRangeSelector: true,
        showInRangeSelector : false, 
        interactionModel: Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel,
        series: {
            "Mean" : {
                drawPoints: false,
                color: "#585858",
            },
            "Scatter" : {
                drawPoints: true,
                pointSize: 3,
                strokeWidth: 0,
            }
        },      
    }
);
</script>
```

Thank you :)

I have to add extra wording because the post is mostly codes and I can't post it :P

Comment: Could you post your code to be able to help you?

Comment: @LucidioVacas Added :)  I made a jfiddle but then you would not be able to see the warning sign :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the workaround I am thinking. Tell me if it is useful for you.

The idea is that you can create another serie only for the rangeselector.

The data for this serie does not matter as it is not going to be shown. But it depends on the way you want to see the range selector. If you want to see the typical line in the rangeselector you can use this first solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/b8sz6m36/4/

```
var hello = [
        [new Date("2016-03-06"),[10,20,30],[11,11,11],[1,1,1]],
        [new Date("2016-03-07"),[10,20,30],[15,15,15],[1,1,1]],
        [new Date("2016-03-08"),[10,20,30],[32,32,32],[1,1,1]],
        [new Date("2016-03-09"),[10,20,30],[18,18,18],[1,1,1]],
        [new Date("2016-03-10"),[10,20,30],[26,26,26],[1,1,1]],
        [new Date("2016-03-11"),[10,20,30],[31,31,31],[1,1,1]],
        [new Date("2016-03-12"),[10,20,30],[9,9,9],[1,1,1]],
    ],

a = new Dygraph(
document.getElementById("hello"),hello, 
{
    labels: [ "Date", "Mean" , "Scatter", "RangeSelector"],
    customBars: true,
    showRangeSelector: true,
    interactionModel: Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel,
    series: {
        "Mean" : {
            drawPoints: false,
            color: "#585858",
                    showInRangeSelector : false, 
        },
        "Scatter" : {
            drawPoints: true,
            pointSize: 3,
            strokeWidth: 0,
                    showInRangeSelector : false, 
        },
        "RangeSelector" : {
            showInRangeSelector : true, 
        }
    },      
  }
);
```

If it does not matter to you to have the range selector completely empty, you can use this second solution where the data in the serie for the rangeselector is simpler

https://jsfiddle.net/b8sz6m36/5/

```
var hello = [
        [new Date("2016-03-06"),[10,20,30],[11,11,11],0],
        [new Date("2016-03-07"),[10,20,30],[15,15,15],0],
        [new Date("2016-03-08"),[10,20,30],[32,32,32],0],
        [new Date("2016-03-09"),[10,20,30],[18,18,18],0],
        [new Date("2016-03-10"),[10,20,30],[26,26,26],0],
        [new Date("2016-03-11"),[10,20,30],[31,31,31],0],
        [new Date("2016-03-12"),[10,20,30],[9,9,9],0],
    ],

a = new Dygraph(
document.getElementById("hello"),hello, 
{
    labels: [ "Date", "Mean" , "Scatter", "RangeSelector"],
    customBars: true,
    showRangeSelector: true,
    interactionModel: Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel,
    series: {
        "Mean" : {
            drawPoints: false,
            color: "#585858",
                    showInRangeSelector : false, 
        },
        "Scatter" : {
            drawPoints: true,
            pointSize: 3,
            strokeWidth: 0,
                    showInRangeSelector : false, 
        },
        "RangeSelector" : {
            showInRangeSelector : true, 
        }
    },      
  }
);
```

Comment: good solution! but there's no way of disabling it right? because huge load of data is generated directly from database, adding another empty data column seem to be redundant

Comment: There is a more efficient solution that works the way you say. You should create your data dygraph without rangeselector and create a new empty one without data but with range selector and to synchronize them using the synchronize.js for dygraph

Answer (score 0):

The showInRangeSelector option has to be set specificly for each one of the series of the graph, not in the general options.
Try setting that option inside the series options to false or true depending on if you want that specific series to appear in the rangeselector

```
a = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("hello"),hello, 
    {
        labels: [ "Date", "Mean" , "Scatter"],
        customBars: true,
        showRangeSelector: true,
        interactionModel: Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel,
        series: {
            "Mean" : {
                drawPoints: false,
                color: "#585858",
                showInRangeSelector : false
            },
            "Scatter" : {
                drawPoints: true,
                pointSize: 3,
                strokeWidth: 0,
                showInRangeSelector : true
            }
        },      
    }
);
```

Comment: yeah I noticed that.. but if I assign both to false it will still pop out a warning sign. Is it possible to show nothing in the range selector? @Lucidio Vacas

Answer (score 0):

I don´t clearly understand why you want to do this, but maybe this is a solution. You have to think in preprocessing the info before creating the dygraph. This way you can show the rangeselector only if any of the series is going to be shown.

```
var showMeanInRangeSelector = false; // or true
var showScatterInRangeSelector = false; // or true
var rangeSelectorVisible = showMeanInRangeSelector || showScatterInRangeSelector;

a = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("hello"),hello, 
  {
    labels: [ "Date", "Mean" , "Scatter"],
    customBars: true,
    showRangeSelector: rangeSelectorVisible,
    interactionModel: Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel,
    series: {
        "Mean" : {
            drawPoints: false,
            color: "#585858",
            showInRangeSelector : showMeanInRangeSelector
        },
        "Scatter" : {
            drawPoints: true,
            pointSize: 3,
            strokeWidth: 0,
            showInRangeSelector : showScatterInRangeSelector
        }
    },      
  }
);
```

Comment: my real data is actually the scatter plot but the small graph in the range selector only shows shaded line graph which would not make sense as a summary of my data. So I want to empty the rangeselector but it looks like not possible. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to upload a jsfiddle and explain a little more we can try to help you. Regards

Comment: this is the jfid: https://jsfiddle.net/b8sz6m36/3/  thanks!
The shaded area is standard deviation and the points are mean of groups of data. In the jfid I enabled the small graph in range selector. It does not represent the data but still I want the range selector function to pan around the graph.